# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d53b6b0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, overlay

I have array of images on camera overlay. When i click button I need to take snapshot of one overlay image with camera view. But I got following error when I launch in device. I searched some existing code I can't get answer.

Error:

```
[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d53b6b0 2013-04-02 11:27:18.748 
    ARimage[1166:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d53b6b0'
```

code for overlay images of array:

```
    NSArray *arrayOfImageFiles=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil];//array of images.

     for(NSString * imageFileName in arrayOfImageFiles)//here you are getting string format but imageFileName is an image object
          {
    UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName];//here imageFileName is image simply give here  UIImage * overlay=imageFileName;
    if(overlay)
        {

       CGSize overlaySize = [overlay size];                                                                    

       [overlay drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor, overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)];                                                                  
        } else {                                                                                                                                      
         NSLog( @"could not find an image named %@", imageFileName);   

           }
          }                                                             
        UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();                          
         [self setStillImage:combinedImage];                                                           
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();                                                     
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];                                    

       }];                                                 
        }
```

Capture overlay image for button click:

```
 - (void)ButtonPressed {

    [self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil]];                                                          

         }
```

Images are displaying in the camera overlay view. When i click the button to capture overlay image i get error.

Comment: once check this one UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName]; in this imageFileName getting from array but in array you are already adding the objectts as images.so here two time allocation

Comment: @Sunny: I didn't get you. explain clearly

Comment: i have edited your code once check it.

Comment: @Sunny: add UIImage * overlay=imageFileName; instead UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName]; Am I correct?

Comment: yes this one correct.

Comment: @Sunny: when i add that line i got warning, Incompatible pointer type initializing 'UIImage *' with an e......

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
 NSArray *arrayOfImageFiles=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil];//array of images.

     for(NSString * imageFileName in arrayOfImageFiles)//here you are getting string format but imageFileName is an image object
          {
      UIImage * overlay=(UIImage *)imageFileName;
    if(overlay)
        {

       CGSize overlaySize = [overlay size];                                                                    

       [overlay drawInRect:CGRectMake(30 * xScaleFactor, 100 * yScaleFactor, overlaySize.width * xScaleFactor, overlaySize.height * yScaleFactor)];                                                                  
        } else {                                                                                                                                      
         NSLog( @"could not find an image named %@", imageFileName);   

           }
          }                                                             
        UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();                          
         [self setStillImage:combinedImage];                                                           
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();                                                     
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];                                    

       }];                                                 
        }
```

Comment: Again get same error. I need to take picture with overlay image. I used AVFoundation framework. Check my button press code. There also i set [self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil]];   Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

This `for` statement:

```
for(NSString * imageFileName in arrayOfImageFiles)
```

makes no sense.  The objects in `arrayOfImageFiles` are instances of UIImage, not `NSString`.  In this line

```
   UIImage * overlay = [UIImage imageNamed: imageFileName];
```

You pass a UIImage as a string parameter which is never going to work.

I think you need to change the code to be like this (making use of the new array initialiser syntax):

```
NSArray *arrayOfImageFileNames = @[@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", @"img4.png", @"img5.png"];

for (NSString* imageFileName in arrayOfImageFileNames)
{  
    // The rest as per your code
}
```

Comment: IS this code correct or wrong for take overlay snapshot - (void)ButtonPressed {

    [self captureStillImageWithOverlay:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"img5.png"], nil]];                                                          

         }

Comment: I don't know.  Does the methods expect an array of strings or images?